# How to write output of "java -version" to a text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I am not able to write the output of `java -version` from a batch file to a text file using:

```
java -version>tmp.txt
```

However, the following works (that is, the data is written to the text file):

```
java>tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command line `java -version` returns the output data at the *STDERR* stream (rather than *STDOUT*). The redirection operator `>` uses the stream handle `1` by default, which is the *STDOUT* stream. To read from the *STDERR* stream, you need to state the respective handle `2` explicitly:

```
java -version 2>tmp.txt
```

The command line `java` behaves as expected, because it returns the output at *STDOUT*.

Reference this external resource for details: [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: You should refer to the documentation... basically, *STDERR* is intended to receive error messages (as the name denotes), all other data is usually written to *STROUT*; but it always depends on the "mood" of the developers...